# Storing deflated HTML in MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, deflate

I need to store HTML data in a MySQL database. I read about this and found that the best method is to use `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR`. Furthermore I'd like to compress the input to make it less space consuming. I use PHP's `gzdeflate()` function for deflating the HTML input, but in this case what MySQL data type should I use?

EDIT: Since I need to store quite big HTML sources I decided to go with the `TEXT` data type but the question: Is MySQL's `TEXT` field compatible with a deflated HTML string?

Answer (score 1):

Use **BLOB** type instead of TEXT to use it for binary data.